# How can I convert a C# multidimensional List to VB.Net

Tags: c#-2.0, vb.net-2010, c#-to-vb.net

I'll start off by saying that everything I know about C# I've learned in the last few days researching how to convert a C# module to VB.Net 4.0.

The code below is a few select lines from the C# module that I'm converting to VB.Net.  For the most part, it has been relatively simple and what I haven't been able to figure out, I've Googled and found an answer for.  After about 10 hours of attempting to search for the answer(s) to the lines below, I finally came here looking for help.

As far as I can tell, the C# code creates a List of Integer, where the Integer is an array.  The lines that I've included below that access that arrayed list.

My question is this: How can I convert this to VB.Net 4.0? or Can someone provide me with the working converted code?

Thanks in advance!

**C# Code:**

```
// mColumnPoint, mStartPoint, mEndPoint are all Integers
// Note that there is a mColumnPoint(int) and mColumnPoints(list) plural

private List<int[]> mColumnPoints;

mColumnPoints = new List<int[]>();

mColumnPoints.Add(new int[] { mStartPoint, mEndPoint });

for (int i = (int)mColumnPoints[mColumnPoint].GetValue(0);
   i < (int)mColumnPoints[mColumnPoint].GetValue(1); i++)
{
    // Stuff in for loop here
}
```

Comment: Sounds lazy but, have you tried to convert using tools? Like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=a29d91a3-639b-40b0-8399-113aa0ff6c4c

Comment: I have not.  But I will take a look that that.  Thanks!

Comment: @CalebC: I just tried that tool and it worked flawlessly...  While I'm ecstatic that it worked, I feel cheated with how fast it did it and the time that I spent researching C#...  I'll get over it though.  Thanks for that link... definitely bookmarked for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It's an easy task:

```
            Dim list As List(Of Integer()) = New List(Of Integer())()
        list.Add(New Integer()() = { Class1.mStartPoint, Class1.mEndPoint })
        For i As Integer = CInt(list(Class1.mColumnPoint).GetValue(0))To CInt(list(Class1.mColumnPoint).GetValue(1)) - 1
        Next
```

I've used a great tool called "ILSpy",
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/files/ILSpy/2.0/ILSpy_Master_2.1.0.1603_RTW_Binaries.zip/download
Simply build what you want using C# or vb.net then open that tool and browse for your *.exe or *.dll to see it in vb.net or c#, have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for that code conversion.  That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Module Module1

Structure segment
    Dim startingPoint As Integer
    Dim endingPoint As Integer
End Structure

Sub Main()

    Dim mStartPoint, mEndPoint, mColumnPoint As Integer

    Dim mColumnPoints As New ArrayList
    Dim nextSegment As segment

    mStartPoint = 1
    mEndPoint = 42
    mColumnPoint = 0  ' The first element in the array

    nextSegment.startingPoint = mStartPoint
    nextSegment.endingPoint = mEndPoint

    mColumnPoints.Add(nextSegment)

    Dim startValue As Integer = mColumnPoints(mColumnPoint).startingPoint
    Dim limit As Integer = mColumnPoints(mColumnPoint).endingPoint

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = startValue To limit
        ' do something
        Console.WriteLine("Cycle # " & i.ToString)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Done " & i.ToString)

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I appreciate you doing this, but since I'm converting existing code I cannot change its intrinsic structure.  If I were able to, I would have done it differently myself.  Thanks for your time and effort just the same.  =)

Comment: Best of luck with your conversion project!  Been there, had to do that.